# Powershell warmup script for multiple sites?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and trying to configure the following warm up script to run against multiple domains:

```
$Site = "http://172.28.36.202:1156/"
$minTime = 250

@($Site) | % {
    Write-Host "Warming up $($_)"
    Do {
        $time = Measure-Command {
            $res = Invoke-WebRequest $_ -Headers @{host="mydomain.com"}
        }
        $ms = $time.TotalMilliSeconds
        If ($ms -ge $minTime) {
            Write-Host "$($res.StatusCode) from $($_) in $($ms)ms" -foreground "yellow"
        }
    } While ($ms -ge $minTime)
    Write-Host "$($res.StatusCode) from $($_) in $($ms)ms" -foreground "cyan"
}
```

Got it working as expected but need to be able to fire the block of code at multiple urls.  Ive got around 25 servers i need to warm up.

Any tips on best way to go about it?  Thanks

Comment: `$Site = "http://172.28.36.202:1156/","http://172.28.36.202:1156/","http://172.28.36.202:1156/","http://172.28.36.202:1156/",etc`

Comment: That's done the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file with all the items you need and read that in to process as needed.

```
$Site = Import-Csv -Path PathToCsvFileWithYourList
```

This way you can leave you script as is, and when yo need to do this for more or less server points, you just change this file.